# XAML get all unnamed controls

Tags: wpf, xml, unit-testing, parsing, xaml

I would like to name all unnamed controls in the xaml files in my project to support automated UI testing.

Can anyone think of way to report on all controls, in all .xaml files in a project without the *x:Name* attribute defined?

Naming the controls will be manual, but I would like to be able to have a test that fails if any .xaml document contains an unnamed control.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2c95f681-d7d6-4d6b-aa8b-9d9a697222b2